# Tinting drawable with transparent makes it disappears

Tags: android

I am trying to set the tinting to transparent so the original drawable is not modified

```
public Drawable getColoredDrawable(int color, int iconId) {
        ColorStateList colorStateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(color);
        Drawable icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), iconId);
        Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(icon);
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawable, colorStateList);
        return wrappedDrawable;
    }
```

When I call getColoredDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT, R.drawable.myDrawable);

Then the drawable is displayed as "blank". Basically no Image at all. But when I set any other color then it works. Why is this happening ?
Thanks

Comment: that's expected behavior. Since if you set the tint to black, the image pixels will be drawn in black. so if you set it to transparent, the image pixels will be drawn in transparent.

Comment: @Snake, what's your expected behavior?

Comment: @Snake As said by Vlad Matvienko its true. If you set transparent drawable you can't see because transparent color code is #00000000 so, when you set transparent to drawable the drawable is their but the color of drawable become transparent.If you really want to see the drawable try #10000000 this color code or you can change the 1 instead of 2,3,4...so on for more and less transparency of drawable.

Comment: Thank you all for explaining the reason. I was expecting the behaviour to be " to show the original drawable". Anyway, I can get the original drawable along with its colors without altering the code above